# How do I mock a class that another class is responsible for instantiating?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection, mocking

Please consider the following code:

```
type
  TFoo1 = class
  public
    procedure DoSomething1;
  end;

  TFoo2 = class
  private
    oFoo1 : TFoo1;
  public
    procedure DoSomething2;
    procedure DoSomething3;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


procedure TFoo1.DoSomething1;
begin
  ShowMessage('TFoo1');
end;

constructor TFoo2.Create;
begin
  oFoo1 := TFoo1.Create;
end;

destructor TFoo2.Destroy;
begin
  oFoo1.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFoo2.DoSomething2;
begin
  oFoo1.DoSomething1;
end;

procedure TFoo2.DoSomething3;
var
  oFoo1 : TFoo1;
begin
  oFoo1 := TFoo1.Create;
  try
    oFoo1.DoSomething1;
  finally
    oFoo1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am creating unit tests for a class and I am stuck on it. My questions are all about the best way to mock objects and the design pattern I should use. The class I am unit testing was not created by me.

1. In the following example, I need to mock `Foo1` because it sends a request to a Web service that I cannot call during my unit testing. But `Foo1` is being created by the `TFoo2` constructor and there's no way I can mock it. What should I do in this case? Should I modify the `TFoo2` constructor to accept the `Foo1` object like this?

   ```
   constructor TFoo2.Create(aFoo1 : TFoo1)
   begin
     oFoo1 := aFoo1;
   end;
   ```

   Is there a design pattern that says we need to pass all objects that a class depends on, like the example above?
2. The method `TFoo2.DoSomething3` creates the `Foo1` object and then frees it. Should I also modify that code to pass a `Foo1` object?

   ```
   procedure TFoo2.DoSomething3(aFoo1 : TFoo1);
   begin
     aFoo1 := aFoo1.DoSomething1;
   end;
   ```
3. Is there any design pattern that support the suggestions I made? If so, I could tell all developers in the company I work for that we need to follow the XXX pattern in order to make unit testing easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cannot mock the creation of `TFoo1`, then you cannot mock `TFoo1`. Right now, `TFoo2` is responsible for creating all instances of `TFoo1`, but if that's not the primary purpose of `TFoo2`, then that is indeed going to make unit-testing hard.

One solution is, as you've suggested, to pass `TFoo2` whatever `TFoo1` instances it needs. That can complicate all your current code that already calls `TFoo2` methods. Another way, which is a little more unit-testing-friendly, is to provide a *factory* for `TFoo1`. The factory can be as simple as a function pointer, or it can be a whole class. In Delphi, *metaclasses* can also serve as factories. Pass the factory to `TFoo2` when it's constructed, and whenever `TFoo2` needs a `TFoo1` instance, it can invoke the factory.

To reduce changes to the rest of your code, you can make the factory parameter have a *default* value in the `TFoo2` constructor. Then you don't have to change your application code. Just change your unit-testing code to provide a non-default factory argument.

Whatever you do, you'll need to make `TFoo1.DoSomething1` be virtual, or else mocking will be futile.

Using metaclasses, your code can look like this:

```
type
  TFoo1 = class
    procedure DoSomethign1; virtual;
  end;

  TFoo1Class = class of TFoo1;

  TFoo2 = class
  private
    oFoo1 : TFoo1;
    FFoo1Factory: TFoo1Class;
  public
    constructor Create(AFoo1Factory: TFoo1Class = nil);
  end;

constructor TFoo2.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FFoo1Factory := AFoo1Factory;
  if not Assigned(FFoo1Factory) then
    FFoo1Factory := TFoo1;

  oFoo1 := FFoo1Factory.Create;
end;
```

Now, your unit-testing code can provide a mock version of `TFoo1` and pass it when it creates a `TFoo2`:

```
type
  TMockFoo1 = class(TFoo1)
    procedure DoSomething1; override;
  end;

procedure TMockFoo1.DoSomething1;
begin
  // TODO: Pretend to access Web service
end;

procedure TestFoo2;
var
  Foo2: TFoo2;
begin
  Foo2 := TFoo2.Create(TMockFoo1);
end;
```

---

Many examples of metaclasses give the base class a *virtual constructor*, but that isn't strictly necessary. You only need to have a virtual constructor if the constructor needs to be called virtually — if the descendant constructor will need to do things with the constructor parameters that the base class doesn't already do. If the descendant (`TMockFoo1`, in this case) does all the same things as its ancestor, then the constructor doesn't need to be virtual. (Also remember that `AfterConstruction` is already virtual, so that's another way to get the descendant to do additional operations without the need for a virtual constructor.)

Comment: Do you know if there is any design pattern that tell us that we need to pass object dependencies through constructor or somethind else? Is it the decorator pattern?

Comment: What you are looking for is Dependency Injection or Inversion of Control.  You've created a dependency of TFoo1 on TFoo2.  You want to,  instead, "inject" TFoo2 into TFoo1 via an interface or the constructor.  Remember, if you are having a hard time writing unit tests, they you aren't doing it right.  ;-)

Comment: +1: I also suggest looking at some of Misko Hevery's articles and You Tube videos. He'll give you some excellent ideas to make your code more testable. Se for example: [Clean Code Talks Dependency Injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/)

Comment: @Nick. Yes, that was exactly the name I was looking for.